# How mock a method with parameters and return an iterable in python

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, mocking, pytest-mock

I need to test this function with a unit test:

```
def nlp_extraction(texts, nlp=None):
    extr = []
    for doc in nlp.pipe([texts]):
        extr.append(list([ent.label_, ent.text]) for ent in doc.ents)
        extracao = [list(extr[i]) for i in range(len(extr))]
        extracao = list(chain.from_iterable(extracao))
        extracao = " ".join([item[1] for item in extracao])
    return [texts, extracao]
```

I wrote, inicialy, this test and worked:

```
def test_nlp_extraction_entrada_correta():
    nlp = loadModel('ner_extract_ingredients')
    result_reference = ['xilitol', 'xilitol']
    texts = 'xilitol'
    result = nlp_extraction(texts, nlp)
    assert result == result_reference
```

But in this test I need to load the model. As this is an unit test, I would like to mock the responses, thus load an external model can be disable. I am trying something like this (and a combination of the lines commented in the code):

```
def test_nlp_extraction_entrada_correta():  
    texts = 'xilitol'

    doc = Mock(name="DOC")
    ents = Mock(name="ENTS", label_='xilitol', text="xilitol")

    doc.ents = [ents]
    
    from nextmock import Mock
    nlp = Mock()
    nlp_mock = Mock()
    nlp.with_args([texts]).returns([doc])
    nlp_mock.pipe = nlp([texts])
    
    # nlp_mock.pipe.with_args([texts]).returns(doc)
    # nlp_mock.pipe = [Mock(return_value=doc)]

    result = nlp_extraction(texts, nlp=nlp_mock)
    assert result == result_reference
```

But an error always raise, saying that nlp.pipe([texts]) mock object is not iterable. So, I need to mock this part nlp.pipe([texts]) and return the doc object. How I can do this? Something I am missing in the proccess, can someone help me.

Comment: The mocked method `nlp.pipe` needs to return an iterable object, so `nlp.pipe.return_value = [doc]`

Comment: On a more general issue: Your default value for `nlp` is `None`, which indicates this parameter is OPTIONAL. But your method would raise an error on `nlp=None`, so this parameter is indeed mandatory and shouldn't have a default value.

Comment: Cpt.Hook Thanks a lot, it worked. About nlp=None you are right, I even can't remember why I set this as None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cpt.Hook said in comments, the solution was achieved using nlp.pipe.return_value = [doc].